# XML XPathResult getting Image url

Tags: xml, image

I have a tag in XML file which looks something like this:

```
<enclosure type="image/jpeg" length="99974" url="something" />
```

how to get the url of an image from this tag ?

for other things I do something like this:

```
var Title = document.evaluate( '//item/title', dom, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?:

```
var Title = document.evaluate('//enclosure/@url', dom, 
                              null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
```